# select a random link from generated search results in C#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, linq, webclient

I am making a wpf application and I need it to select a link at random from the generated search results. I have no idea how to go about doing that. It is just an intellectual exercise I was assigned. please help i am almost done. Here is the code so far... I am a super beginner at WPF.

```
namespace Search
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
            {
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText(_textBox.Text);
                browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

                browser.WaitForComplete(5000);

                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}"); // presses search on the second screen

                browser.Button(Find.ById("gbqfb")/*.ByName("btnG")*/).Click(); // doesn't work



            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some **indicative** code...

```
private void DownloadRandomLink(string searchTerm)
{
    string fullUrl = "http://www.google.com/#q=" + searchTerm;
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(fullUrl, "file.htm");
    Random rand = new Random();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file.htm");
    var linksOnPage = from lnks in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                      where lnks.Name == "a" &&
                            lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
                            lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                      select new
                          {
                              Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                              Text = lnks.InnerText
                          };
    if (linksOnPage.Count() > 0)
    {
        int randomChoice = rand.Next(0, linksOnPage.Count()-1);
        var link = linksOnPage.Skip(randomChoice).First();
        // do something with link...
    }
}
```

This code takes a search term and builds a full Google url.  It then downloads the query into a local file, and opens the file with HTML Agility Pack.

Then the code creates a list of all the links on the page and uses a cobbled-together randomized selection.

As others have mentioned, you will need to get Google's permission to run the code against their servers.  Not doing so places you in breach and may have awkward consequences.

Also, this code is **indicative**; it's not meant to be **exemplary**, or even **buildable**.  It's a rough idea of the steps needed to get what you are after.

Your earlier design was attempting to interact with controls on Google's index page and that kind of approach is way too brittle in the first instance.  You can't hardly test it for starters.

The HTML Agility Pack is here http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples